Enhanced Full Calendar List View with button, but click has no effect
I added several buttons with toggle-actions (showing just one expl. below) to full calendar list view, but none of them is clickable. The togglePublic-function is available and I also made the height 1 point higher than event-click-layer via z-index.
Just the event-click-action is triggered.
eventContent: (arg) => {
      let paragraph = document.createElement('div');
      let public = document.createElement('div');

      paragraph.className = 'event';
      public.className = 'public';

      if (arg.event.extendedProps.public === true) {
        public.innerHTML = '<button style="width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: green; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px;" (click)="togglePublic(' + arg.event.id + ')"><i class="material-icons">public</i></button>';
      } else {
        public.innerHTML = '<button style="width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: red; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px;" (click)="togglePublic(' + arg.event.id + ')"><i class="material-icons">public</i></button>';
      }

      paragraph.appendChild(public);

      return { domNodes: [paragraph] };
    },
    eventClick: this.openEditEventDialog.bind(this)


There are a few ways you could achieve this.
N.B. These are native JS examples as I'm not an Angular user, but I would expect you can get the same behaviour using the equivalent Angular code, since Angular just builds on top of native JS.


Using onclick it seems it will detect the click on the <i class="material-icons"> within your button, because that's directly the element the user would have clicked.

So just move the click code onto that element:
if (arg.event.extendedProps.public === true) {
  public.innerHTML = '<button style="width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: green; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px;"><i class="material-icons" onclick="togglePublic(' + arg.event.id + ');">public</i></button>';
} else {
  public.innerHTML = '<button style="width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: red; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px;"><i class="material-icons" onclick="togglePublic(' + arg.event.id + ');">public</i></button>';
}

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BaeeyoZ


You could add an external event listener onto the <i> - it will need to use delegated event handling, since the buttons may not be rendered until after the listener has been added.

This requires a class and data-attribute adding to the <i>:
if (arg.event.extendedProps.public === true) {
  public.innerHTML = '<button style="width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: green; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px;"><i class="material-icons eventButton" data-id="' + arg.event.id + '">public</i></button>';
} else {
  public.innerHTML = '<button style="width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: red; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px;"><i class="material-icons eventButton" data-id="' + arg.event.id + '">public</i></button>';
}

And then a separate event listener:
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("eventButton")) {
    togglePublic(e.target.dataset.id);
  }
});

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzbbPgQ


You could use the eventClick callback to detect which specific item within the event's HTML was clicked.

Again this requires a class adding to the <i> - but the data attribute isn't needed since the arguments to eventClick can give you the event ID already.
if (arg.event.extendedProps.public === true) {
  public.innerHTML = '<button style="width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: green; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px;"><i class="material-icons eventButton">public</i></button>';
} else {
  public.innerHTML = '<button style="width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: red; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px;"><i class="material-icons eventButton">public</i></button>';
}

and then the eventClick handler:
eventClick: (arg) => {
  if (arg.jsEvent.target.classList.contains("eventButton")) {
    togglePublic(arg.event.id);
  }
}

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYaaNwW

Of course if you want to handle click events on any other parts of the event's HTML, you can apply exactly the same principles to those elements.

Thx for your full explanation and help. Everything is correct, but I decided not to go further the JS way. I thought there would be an angular way, to manipulate the view of full-calendar list view. Regards

After some time I found a solution for this:
eventContent: (arg) => {
  let paragraph = document.createElement('div');
  let publicity = document.createElement('button');

  publicity.addEventListener('click', () => this.togglePublicity(parseInt(arg.event.id)));
  
  paragraph.className = 'event';
  publicity.innerHTML = '<i class="material-icons">public</i>';

  if (arg.event.extendedProps.public === true) {
    publicity.setAttribute('style', 'width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: green; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px; position: relative; z-index: 999');
  } else {
    publicity.setAttribute('style', 'width: 36px; height: 36px; background-color: red; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 18px; position: relative; z-index: 999');
  }

  paragraph.appendChild(publicity);
  
  return { domNodes: [paragraph] };
}

[...]

async togglePublicity(eventId: number): Promise<void> {
  let toggledEvent = await firstValueFrom(this.eventService.togglePublicityOfEventById(eventId));
  let calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
  let givenEvent = calendarApi.getEventById(eventId.toString());
  givenEvent.setExtendedProp("public", toggledEvent.public);
}

With on issue left: The Toggle Button works as expected, but it also opens the related Item, because the area is also a click-area for editing the Item. Can I stop this behaviour?

I could pass the event when adding the eventlistener and do a stopPropagation on it - that finally works: publicity.addEventListener('click', (event) => this.togglePublicity(parseInt(arg.event.id), event)); and then in the method: event.stopPropagation();
